# How to install mosh on oracle linux

Tags: linux, ssh, yum, packages, oracle-linux

I wanted to install **mosh** on **oracle linux**, but I was faced with the fact that such a package does not exist.

```
$ sudo yum install mosh
Last metadata expiration check: 3:12:40 ago on Wed 15 Feb 2023 01:05:56 PM GMT.
No match for argument: mosh
Error: Unable to find a match: mosh
```

I tried to build mosh from the source code, but that didn't work either.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/mobile-shell/mosh
$ cd mosh
$ ./autogen.sh
./autogen.sh: line 3: exec: autoreconf: not found
```

After that, I tried to install the dependencies, and I was faced with the fact that not all dependencies can be installed, for example ncurses(libncurses5-dev)

Can I install mosh on oracle linux and how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find `mosh` package in EPEL repo. [Here](https://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/epel/9/x86_64/Packages/m/mosh-1.4.0-1.el9.x86_64.html) is the page for RHEL/Oracle 9. To install it use [this](https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL9/developer/EPEL/x86_64/index.html) repo.